# How to bootstrap a node automatically?

Tags: chef-infra

I have multiple nodes to bootstrap. I don't want to type knife bootstrap command for every node with their FQDN manually. How to bootstrap a node and delete a node automatically, without doing it manually? otherwise is it possible to bootstrap multiple nodes with single knife bootstrap command.Any suggestions...

Answer (score 0):

I've always used a simple script to read from a json or yaml file and loop through the nodes.  That also allowed me to include a run_list and set of attributes for each node (if they are different).

Answer (score 0):

I tried this a long time ago and was frustrated with the inability to do such a thing. I was working in ec2, so the username was the same, but it was something like below.

It's not a pretty script and it runs sequentially so it may take some time, but it was a quick way to just give it a list and go.

Input like

```
./bootstrap.sh "0.0.0.0:name 1.1.1.1:name2 2.2.2.2:name3"
```

The input has to be quoted like above for it to work properly, I didn't want to get into command line parsing, just wanted something simple to work.

```
#!/usr/bin/bash

export IFS=" "

echo "Got server list..."
echo $1

for PAIR in $1; do
        SERVER=`echo $PAIR | cut -d: -f1`
        NAME=`echo $PAIR | cut -d: -f2`
        #knife bootstrap $SERVER -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -N $NAME -r "runlist" -j '{"json":"json"}'
        echo "knife bootstrap $SERVER -x ec2-user -i ~/.ssh/key.pem -N $NAME -r "runlist" -j '{"json":"json"}'"
done
```

This right now just prints out the command it would run, you'd have to uncomment the line above to actually run the command. As pointed out above, it's probably a better idea to write some ruby around it.

Oh and as far as deleting many nodes in one command you could look into bulk delete via knife.

https://docs.chef.io/knife_node.html#bulk-delete

Answer (score 0):

I use standard shell tricks like looping and awk

### Bulk bootstrapping

Run the bootstrap within a loop:

```
for n in host1 host2 host3; do knife bootstrap $n -x -sudo -x user -r role[myapp]; done
```

runs the following commands:

```
knife bootstrap host1 -x -sudo -x user -r role[myapp]
knife bootstrap host2 -x -sudo -x user -r role[myapp]
knife bootstrap host3 -x -sudo -x user -r role[myapp]
```

### Purge all nodes

The following command purges all nodes on the chef server (warning!)

```
knife node list | awk '{printf "knife node delete %s -y\nknife client delete %s -y\n",$1,$1}' | bash
```

By running the following series of commands:

```
knife node delete host1 -y
knife client delete host1 -y
knife node delete host2 -y
knife client delete host2 -y
knife node delete host3 -y
knife client delete host3 -y
```